Granular auditing options with PowerBI
Good afternoon,
Looking for advice or documentation on the auditing capabilities of Power BI. Specifically, whether they offer auditing on user interaction with dashboards. We currently have a proprietary application which hosts data analytics and since we are in control, I can log every request received and response delivered. If a user changes a value for slicing the dataset, I can see the change in the API request and log the resulting dataset.
Colleagues have reviewed and lean towards it not being an option but I was a little surprised by this and found some documents that make me lean the other way. So, is this granularity something Power BI offers?
Thank you!
